# create names with vba and offset reference

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently working on an Excel File with VBA. I need to create about 500 names which is manually almost impossible.

So what I am looking for is to generate the names with VBA. I have tried this code so far:

```
wb.Names.Add Name:=myName & "BAN", RefersToR1C1:= "'OFFSET('sheet1'!$C$7:$C$206;0;0;COUNT('sheet1'!$C$7:$C$206))'"
```

for example, myName is an array with 25 names. The aim is to have a loop, that creates 25 named ranges with the reference of the Offset command. What I have problems with is to create a loop, which changes the reference cells $C$7:$C$206. Because the column should be variable (there are 25 names which refer to 25 columns). 
I would be really glad if somebody could give me a hint!

Best
Elio

Comment: You could do the offsetting from an anchor column, say C7:C206, then the columns loop could offset from this, so myName(loop number) C7:C206.offset(rowcount,loop number) so would translate to offset(C7:C206,0,1), offset(C7:C206,0,2) and so on. Or use the same, but get the .Address to get the ranges

Comment: For intLoop =0 to ubound(myName):wb.names.add name:=myName(intLoop),RefersToR1C1="'OFFSET('sheet1'!$C$7:$C$206;0;" & intloop & "; etc etc " : Next intLoop.    I am not able to do the code in VBA at the minute, but something similar to this

Comment: Dear Nathan_Sav
Thank you very much for your answer. I will try it out, modify and see if it works :)

Comment: So I tried several things, unfortunately I still not figured out how to manage it. I have prepared a very simple example of the code

Alpha and Beta are the column names. These should be used to generate the 2 names, so that means columns in the code have to adjust from $C$ to $D$.

`Sub create_names_4()

    Dim myName As Variant
    myName = Array("Alpha", "Beta")

    For intLoop = 0 To UBound(myName)
        wb.Names.Add Name:=myName(intLoop), RefersToR1C1:= _
        "OFFSET('sheet1'!$C$7:$C$206" & intLoop & ";0;0;COUNT('sheet1'!$C$7:$C$206))"
    Next intLoop

End Sub`

Comment: You need to set your row count to be the same offset i'd imagine, otherwise it will be dynamic to c, not the actual column.

Comment: Thank you Nathan_Sav for your helpful comments!